# How to populate data from JSON using AJAX in TypeScript?

Tags: ajax, json

I have data attribute in my HTML page. I have a JSON file "rss.json". I am not getting the typescript code to call the JSON using AJAX.

```
<div class="js-rssfeed" data-url="rss.json"></div> //HTML
```

//TypeScript Code

```
 class RSSFeedManager {
 "use strict";

 private rootSelectionString: string = ".js-rssfeed";


 private $rootSelector: JQuery; 
constructor() {
     var base = this;
    base.$rootSelector = $(base.rootSelectionString);
    base.rssValidate();

}
private rssValidate() {
var base=this;
  if(base.$rootSelector.length!==0) {
        //getRssFeedJson();
    }
}   
}

var _RSSFeedManager = new RSSFeedManager();
export = _RSSFeedManager;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **$.getJSON** Jquery function you can load JSON data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

```
/////
     private rssValidate() {
        var base=this;
          if(base.$rootSelector.length!==0) {

                var jsonUrl = base.$rootSelector(base.$rootSelectionString).attr('data-url'); 
                $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }   
        }
///////
```

hope this help

Comment: ok try now , i have edited my code

Comment: Its giving the same error!!!
But I have corrected it by 
   var jsonUrl = $(".js-rssfeed").data('url');

Thanks

Comment: or you can do this replace it to `var jsonUrl = jQuery(base.$rootSelector).attr('data-url');`

Comment: ohh thats great!!!

Comment: Can I do the same with AJAX?

Comment: Yes, you can see this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ ,  but getJSON is a shorthand Ajax function.

Comment: Please guide me if there is XML instead of JSON
Then how will I fetch data in typescript using AJAX?